По "окончанию" или по "окончании", завершению или завершении?
Заполненный путевой лист по завершению поездки передается в отдел учета. Водитель поставил свою подпись по окончанию смены.


Правильно: по окончании, по завершении (П. п.).

Здесь значение времени:  когда завершилась поездка, когда окончилась смена.
№ 319225
Здравствуйте. Подскажите как правильно писать "по окончании" или "по окончанию"?
Ответ.
Во временно́м значении правильно по окончании (школы, недели и т. п.).

Другие значения (Д. п.) возможны крайне редко. См. тему

